# After permit, the parameter with the attached file disappears, Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

Here is the designation of those parameters that I want to permit:

```
@@BODY_ATTRIBUTES = {
  NmhOrder: StudentsController.body_attributes(NmhOrder),
  TechOrder: StudentsController.body_attributes(TechOrder),
  quotation_file: {}
}

@@ORDER_ATTRIBUTES = [
  :id, :student_id, :user_id, :acceptance_letter_file,
  :arranged, :pickup, :notes, :order_type_id,
  :order_status_id,
  :body_attributes => @@BODY_ATTRIBUTES.values.union.flatten,
  :labels => []
]
```

That's how I use it:

```
params.require(:student).permit [
  :id, :crn, :contact_number, :postcode, :city, :address, :notes, :user_id, :hep_id, :acceptance_letter_required,
  :funding_body_id, :pref_communication_way => [],
  :user_attributes => [:id, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :role],
  :orders_attributes => @@ORDER_ATTRIBUTES
]
```

Params i had before permit:

> #<ActionController::Parameters {"student"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>755358195, "orders_attributes"=>[#<ActionController::Parameters {"quotation_file"=>{"original_filename"=>"mock letter.pdf", "tempfile"=>"#File:0x0000557e247852d8", "content_type"=>"application/pdf"}, "labels"=>[1], "id"=>435112486, "body_attributes"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"is_contribute_payable"=>true} permitted: false>} permitted: false>]} permitted: false>, "controller"=>"students", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"755358195"} permitted: false>

But after permit i get:

> #<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>755358195, "orders_attributes"=>[#<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>435112486, "body_attributes"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"is_contribute_payable"=>true} permitted: true>, "labels"=>[1]} permitted: true>]} permitted: true>

As you see, i loose quotation_file, help do something with this, please

Comment: Well, you don't permit `quotation_file` anywhere, so no wonder it disappears.

Comment: in @@BODY_ATTRIBUTES i have quotation_file, is it inccorect?

Comment: You do, but that key is never used. You only read `values` from that hash.

Comment: how can i use it?

Comment: I suggest you take a few steps back and write it in the simplest possible way: everything in just one `permit`, no extracted hashes, merging hashes or anything like that. Once you get that working, you can cleanup/refactor.

Comment: i tried, if i add in orders_attributes only { :quotation_file => {} }, it does not disappear, but i cant add both @@ORDER_ATTRIBUTES and quotation_file in one permit

Comment: quotation_file is in `@@BODY_ATTRIBUTES` above.  Is that right?

Comment: @MarkSwardstrom I really don't know what's right here. This is one of the many quotation_file placement options I've tried. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It's submitted as a child of the Orders Attributes, but permitted as a child of the Body Attributes.  Those need to sync up first.